# Magento 2 : How Can Directly Upload Video to Product

Tags: magento2, product, admin, file-upload, video

I know that, we can upload video via Vimeo and Youtube video url in the product from admin.

However I cannot find a way to directly upload video file same as product image.

Does this means that I cannot host product video in my Magento server?

Comment: you have two options for upload video in magento 2. 1) upload video via google drive (http://blog.belvg.com/how-to-add-a-video-to-a-product-in-magento-2-0.html) 2) install third party extension to upload video (https://www.fmeextensions.com/product-videos-magento-2.html)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution, if you don't want to use YouTube or Vimeo, upload file directly in to your server, and using browser native html video tag, you can insert video manually. Just simple example bellow, inside product page description.

```
<video width="480" controls>
  <source src="/pub/media/video/your-video-file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Hi @crashtestxxx, your solution is for displaying video in product detail page in either description or in tabbing section but if i want to display inside Product Image gallery (fotorama gallery), do you have any idea how to do with this for configurable product.

Comment: @NayanBaraiya As of this moment, Magento 2 supports only YouTube and Vimeo video uploads. To be able to upload and host video files on same server and be used with build in Magento 2 gallery, you will need to write module extension. Instead, if YouTube and Vimeo is not an option, I would suggest just purchase ready to install module, it will save you time and frustrations.

Comment: Can you suggest any extension for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If Display video in product page using mp4 video and another types of video

We have to need create attribute for add video name

Then get this video name to where want to display video

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
?>

<?php if($proVideo = $_helper->productAttribute($_product,$_product->getVideoName(), 'video_name')):?>
    <?php $videoUrl = $this->getUrl('pub/media/catalog/product/videos/').$proVideo; ?>
    <div class="prod_video_bg">
        <video width="400" controls>
          <source src="<?php echo $videoUrl; ?>" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: whats problems and face error explain in brief

Comment: i have add this code video link its not getting my phtml page

Comment: $proVideo = $_helper->productAttribute($_product,$_product->getVideoName(), 'video_name')

Ru u not geeting this value right ?

Comment: value not display in this page NULL value

Comment: Have you create attribut : video_name for product ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101166/discussion-between-baharuni-asif-and-sudhakar-arunachalam).

Comment: @SUDHAKAR ARUNACHALAM Have you got solution or not ??

Answer (score 0):

This extension might be useful https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-product-video/

Answer (score -4):

Yes, you can only upload video to Magento 2 product via YouTube or Vimeo.